# Zend Framework convert NULL string to actual NULL value for MySql

Tags: zend-framework, null, insert

Somehow when doing an import of data into mysql using a multi-row insert with execute() function, there were many rows added with the string NULL for some columns.
How can I convert those NULL strings into MySQL NULL values so that I can check for empty values using is_null() in php when displaying data.

How can I avoid this problem? I was using the quote() function for each piece of data. Was that the problem using quote on empty fields? I was importing a csv file.

thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To insert an SQL NULL or any other expression, you can use a `Zend_Db_Expr` object.  Even if you use `quote()`, ZF passes these objects through unquoted.

```
$null = new Zend_Db_Expr("NULL");

$table = new MyTable();
$table->insert(123, "abc", $null);
```

Note that because use of `Zend_Db_Expr` bypasses both quoting and parameterization, you're responsible for protecting against SQL injection.

---

This is tangential to your question, but consider [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) if you're bulk-loading a CSV file.  It can be 20x faster than even using multi-row `INSERT`.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Just what I was looking for. So when iterating through data for an insert, I should be looking for empty data and not use quote() but use new Zend_Db_Expr("NULL") for that empty data?
I'm definitely going to look into that LOAD_DATA_INFILE function. I guess I can load data into a temporary table, then do my data functions on it, then delete it.

Comment: Yes, you can do some postprocessing via a temp table (btw you don't have to drop a temp table, since it goes away when your db connection closes).  You could alternatively use the optional `SET` clause of `LOAD DATA INFILE` to do some limited data transformation.  See the docs.